# Загрузка контенте без перезагрузки

Tags: ajax, javascript

На сайте http://gazgolder.com при нажатии на верхнем меню страница меняется без перезагрузки(это делается не сложно), но вот как сделать так чтобы менялся url адрес, и при прямом переходе по нему открывалась не главная а та которая указана в url???
Скажите кто знает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь этим [jquery address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/),в примерах к нему есть решение вашей проблемы!

Answer (score 3):

Обычно на AJAX сайтах при "переходах" меняют хэш — часть адресной строки после «решётки» `#`. Например, было `www.site.ru/`, стало `www.site.ru/#stranica-pro-traktor`, потом перешли на другую, стало `www.site.ru/#kontakty`

При первичной загрузке страницы нужно JS'ом выбрать хэш, если он есть, и подгрузить сразу же нужную часть. Это можно сделать только JS'ом, т.к. на сервер при HTTP запросе часть после хэша не передаётся.

Делал так, к примеру, [на своём сайте](http://sergeisokolov.com/#ru/print), хотя он без PHP, и загружаемый HTML сразу содержит данные для всех секций. Ссылка сразу ведёт на раздел про печать, и меняется при переходе между разделами.

Answer (score 2):

В новых браузерах есть такая фича как

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title",byurl);
window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title",byurl);
```

Дает возможность подменить урл без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант использовать хэш навигацию. Как уже сказано в одном из комментариев, используется часть url после знака "#", линки навигации содержат соответственно линки вида

```
<a href="#contacts">Обратная связь</a>
```

как известно линки которые начинаются на "#" определятся в как линки которые ведут на текущую страницу, и, соотвественно, при клике на них перехода на другую страницу не происходит. Дальше вся фишка в использовании javascript'ом события 'hashchange', которое срабатывает при изменении части url после "#" и свойства window.location.hash, в котором хранится нужная часть url. В обработчик данного события ставится загрузка ajax'ом содержимого страницы на которую совершается переход.

Пр:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
  var pageName = window.location.hash;
  $.get(
    "content.php", 
    { page: pageName }, 
    function(data) {
      $('#content').html(data);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: стоит учесть, что по умолчанию, у сайта, использующего данный тип навигации, будут проблемы с видимостью в поисковиках. Для решения этого вопроса от google в статье https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=ru-RU

Comment: Ну дык не нужно просто юзать hash, нужно юзать History API и не нужно читать всякую хрень придуманную гуглом.

Answer (score 1):

Есть jQuery [плагин jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser)  ставите себе на сайт вот этот файл purl.js (из дистрибутива) 
А потом что бы вытащить GET параметр из URL-а пишем например такую переменную, ну или как удобно

```
var urlPage = $.url().param("page");
```

`.param("page")` параметр здесь это `page`. То есть ссылка должна иметь такой вид:

```
mysite.ru/?page=1
```

Таким макаром можно написать условие

```
If(urlPage == 1) {
    //действие, например .load
}
```